# Difference in transition lifetimes for near-resonant v/s non-resonant Raman effect

Tags: spectroscopy, resonance, raman

I have read that a virtual state is created when Raman scattering occurs. Since this state is forbidden, the molecule upon absorbing a photon (not enough to take it to the next electronically excited level) immediately gives off the stokes or anti-stokes shifted photon with delay in the order of femto-seconds. If the photon were to be energetic enough to take it close to the excited state(near-resonant), would there be a change in the lifetime of the transition?

Comment: The dephasing of the excited molecule+light field is important here, but this is complicated; see eqns 9.15-9.19 chapter 9 in S. Mukamel, 'Nonlinear Optical Spectroscopy', (Publ OUP), not an easy read but he connects theory with experiment very clearly.